# Can you cast a spell at a higher level, even if it doesn't have an "At higher levels" entry?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting, spell-slots

Many spells have "At higher levels" that provides for more targets or more damage.

For example Magic Missile can be cast as a second level spell and shoot 4 missiles instead of it's 3 as a first level spell.

Can a spell without that verbiage, such as Firestorm be cast in higher level slots for the same effect as the lower level spell?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### Yes, you can cast any spell of 1st level or higher using a higher-level spell slot.

The Spellcasting feature for every class that has it, such as the [cleric](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#Spellcasting-108) or the [wizard](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#Spellcasting-410), includes the following sentence:

> To cast [one of your class’s spells of 1st level or higher], you must expend a slot of the spell’s level or higher.

This is expanded upon in the description of ["Spell Slots"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#SpellSlots):

> When a character casts a spell, he or she expends a slot of that spell's level or higher, effectively "filling" a slot with the spell. You can think of a spell slot as a groove of a certain size--small for a 1st-level slot, larger for a spell of higher level. A 1st-level spell fits into a slot of any size, but a 9th-level spell fits only in a 9th-level slot.

Only some spells specify an increased effect from using a higher slot. All others have the same effect regardless of which level slot they are cast in.

However, any spell of 1st level or higher can be cast using a spell slot of a higher level, regardless of whether it has any greater effect when you do so.

Comment: It would also be an onerous restriction on Warlocks to no longer be able to cast lower-level spells when they attained a higher level, since their spells are always cast at the highest level possible.